# Calling a Method from another file in C#

Tags: c#, methods, calling-convention

I am a beginner in C#. I have written some functions in moving_phone.cs

I have another file Program.cs in a separate project where I need to run the functions I have written in moving_phone.cs. Each file has different namespaces and are drastically different from each other.

How can I do that?

I have looked for solutions online but could only find results where the files shared the same namespace, or the tutorials were much to specific for me to translate towards my own solution.

Comment: How are you compiling this code?  If these files are in the same "project" (are you using Visual Studio?) then you can reference one from the other directly.  If they're in separate "projects" then one project would need to reference the other.  Please provide a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: If you want to call a method in another assembly, you need to reference the assembly first. If both of your projects are in one solution, this would be a project reference.

Comment: Please show the structure of your project and your classes (excerpts should be sufficient, just make sure to provide a *minimal, reproducible example* as mentioned by David). You may also want to check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In response to `Each file has different namespaces and are drastically different from each other.` There is no need to specify different name spaces for *every* different file, what you should be doing is making a different namespace for different *projects* in the solution. Looking at this from a Model-View-Controller architecture shows why this makes sense: for ex. all your DTO's are in `MySolution.Model`, your unit tests are all in `MySolution.Test`. To make different namespaces for different files is needlessly complex and will be confusing to others looking at your code

Comment: Say you have `Person`, `Employee`, `Teacher`, `Firefighter` classes. Would you rather import *n* number of namespaces where *n* is the number of different classes referenced in that file? Or would you rather simply one `using MySolution.Humans;`? The choice is yours

Answer (score 1):

> I have another file Program.cs in a separate project

First, C# allows top-level statements and methods now, but the functions in `moving_phone.cs` need to be contained in a **type**, such as a class, struct, or record, if you want to use them in a separate project.

It also matters now whether this separate project is in the same solution as `Program.cs` or a different solution. If it's a different solution, you must build the project containing `moving_phone.cs`, so you have a dll or exe file (an **assembly**). Then, you can add add a reference to this assembly from the `Program.cs` solution. If both are in the same Visual Studio solution, you get this reference by default.

Now you can refer to the type(s) in `moving_phone.cs` that contain your methods from within `Program.cs` using the fully-qualified name (includes the namespace), or by adding a `using` directive for the namespace at the top of the file.

Finally, it matters whether these are `static` methods. If they are static, you can call them using `typeName.MethodName()` syntax. If they are not static, you must first create an instance of the type.